# Please clear up the following confusion about Faraday's law, electromotive force, magnetic inductance, and current

Tags: magnetic-fields, electromagnetic-induction, inductance

[image]

As the magnet moves from the outside, the magnetic flux that is linked to the circuit is [pi_0 sin(wt)].

We have listed a series of processes related to electromotive force, self-inductance L, and current in a circuit.

1. The magnetic flux linking the circuit changes.
2. Electromotive force is generated according to Faraday's law.

Question 1.

Current flows according to electromotive force, but there is no resistance,

only self-inductance L. Then current I = voltage EMF / impedance jwL?

Question 2.

What is the action of self-inductance L?

L opposes the change in current.

Then, the magnetic flux linkage changes in the circuit from the outside,

and according to Faraday's law, an electromotive force is generated in the direction of counteracting the change,

and then a current flows,

and the magnetic inductance L acts in the direction of counteracting the current again.

Then, is L an action in the same direction as the original external magnetic flux?

Comment: It is not clear what you want, where does your $\omega in sin(\omega t) $ come from . L is a characteristic of a coil it is nothing like an action.